# Clojure instant/parse-timestamp usage

Tags: rest, clojure, datomic, instant

A clojure newbie question. I am trying to figure out the best way to pass a date from a client (written in any language) to a server written in clojure that rests on a Datomic database. To avoid any problems with language specific classes I was planning to pass the date as a RFC3339 formatted string. However, I'm having trouble parsing the string in Clojure. My, apparently erroneous, assumption was that I could do:

```
(clojure.instant/parse-timestamp "2014")
```

and thus get an instant. However, this call results in

```
clojure.lang.ArityException: Wrong number of args (1) passed to: instant$fn--6183$fn …
```

This confuses me greatly since as far as I can see this function only takes a single argument (formatted string).

What have I missed?

Comment: Just noticed that parse-timestamp is a variable not a function. But I still wonder how it's used to parse a string.

Comment: Global functions live in `var`s. See [`def`](http://clojure.org/special_forms#def). `defn` is based on `def`.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`parse-timestamp` is a function of two arguments. The string representation of a timestamp is the second one. The first one is for passing in a function that takes a bunch of arguments and constructs an object representing an instant. The arguments to this `new-instant` function are described in the docstring of `parse-timestamp` -- see `(doc clojure.instant/parse-timestamp)` for details.

Normally you don't need to call `parse-timestamp` directly, as `clojure.instant` exports a bunch of functions for reading in timestamps:

```
(clojure.instant/read-instant-date "2014-04-23T10:13Z")
;= #inst "2014-04-23T10:13:00.000-00:00"
```

`read-instant-calendar` and `read-instant-timestamp` are the other two functions of this type. They're all built using `parse-timestamp` and have docstrings documenting their contracts.